# Jquery, autocomplete values not showing on modal view

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's code

```
   $('#user_id').autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: $('#user_id').data('autocomplete-source'),
    autoFocus: true
   });
```

autocomplete suggestions values showing behind the modal view.

Comment: Can you add snippet with _modal view_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the z-index for the autocomplete element to be larger than modal element. Can use css class or inline style.

Comment: thanks for responding and giving answer. It's working now